# Does Instagram API have any endpoint for deleting a media object (photo / video)

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to delete all the images/videos of my Instagram account without deleting my account. Doing this manually is taking so much time so I thought maybe I can implement a server-side app that send request to API considering the rate constraints etc. But I can't find any endpoints in Instagram API documentation for delete function of media objects.

I wonder if anyone has any knowledge for this purpose ? I saw some 3rd party apps provide this functionality as a paid service, I wonder if anyone know how they are doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no official endpoints can do this. The only DELETE method is for comments. However, if you don't care about the api is official or not, maybe you can try https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/issues/38 .

Comment: thanks for your help but I couldn't understand how someone can come up with an unofficial method for this purpose.